# c vim garbles 1st character of file when using via mobaxterm

Tags: ssh, vim, freebsd, mobaxterm

this thing drives me crazy, and I am unable to find a solution...

I am logging in to a FreeBSD machine via ssh using MobaXterm. Every time I open a text file with vim, it replaces the first character of the file with 'g'. It is not just garbling the display, when I try to quit vim, it warns me that the file has been changed, and after writing the file the 'g' is in there of course.

The only thing I was able to figure out that this only happens when TERM is set to an xterm variant (xterm, xterm-color, etc.). It does not happen when using other editors (nano or vi).

Could anyone suggest a solution or point me to the right direction what should I check or reconfigure?

Update:

The output of :scriptnames

```
  1: /usr/local/etc/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  6: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
  7: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
  8: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/logiPat.vim
  9: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
 10: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 11: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 12: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
 13: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 14: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
 15: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 16: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

I don't have a .vimrc file in my home directory, the one in /usr/local/etc/vim is the unmodified default file that came with the vim package:

```
if v:lang =~ "utf8$" || v:lang =~ "UTF-8$"
        set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1
endif

let g:is_posix = 1
set nocompatible
set bs=indent,eol,start
set history=50
set ruler

if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
        syntax on
        set hlsearch
endif

if has("autocmd")
        augroup freebsd
        autocmd!
        if $PORTSDIR != ""
                autocmd BufNewFile $PORTSDIR/*/*/Makefile 0r $PORTSDIR/Templates/Makefile
        else
                autocmd BufNewFile /usr/ports/*/*/Makefile 0r /usr/ports/Templates/Makefile
        endif
endif
```

It happens when opening text or binary files.
The issue seems to be related to MobaXterm however; it happens only when I connect with MobaXterm. Vim works normally when I use putty or the physical console ($TERM is xterm in both cases).

Comment: Does that happen with all file types you open with vim? Please post your vimrc and which plugins you load on start.

Comment: Which version of Vim are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the missing version number, it was 7.4.752. Since then I have upgraded to 7.4.826, but it did not fix the issue. 826 is the latest FreeBSD port available, but I haven't seen any fixes related to this in the README between 826 and the current version (841).
As this seems to be an issue with MobaXterm and not with vim, I think I'll stick with putty for the moment. Anyway, thanks for the respnonses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug, that has recently been fixed. Please update your Vim.

Oh and in case of the mobaxterm, this also seems to be a [bug of the mobaxterm](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/_Q26KGKB5nk/jQmUmbbm-kIJ)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: As there were no specific version information, I couldn't be more precise. Also this is more suited for vim-dev ml rather then superuser.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt - You should seek the clarification from the author then before you submit an answer.  You believe this to be a bug, prove it was a bug, and show when it was fixed.  The current revision isn't all that helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound. Thanks. I provide enough patches that I know. Thanks for telling me

Comment: See my comment under the question about version numbers. 
I could not figure out where the root cause of this could be: a vim issue, a bug in mobaxterm or a freebsd configuration problem. I'll test the issue on  a linux box tomorrow. I'll send feedback to the vim-dev list if I find out something vim-related.
Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: see update. looks like a bug of mobaxterm.

Comment: I can confirm, this is the same issue as mentioned in the link in your edit. Thanks a lot for your efforts!

Update: seems it has been fixed in mobaxterm 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `~/.vimrc` file:

`set background=dark`

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem.
I don't have the solution to fix it.
But I do have a workaround to avoid it.

You can install 'tmux' and use vim on tmux, the 'g' issue would be gone.